# Get element-wise extreme values of multiple arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given multiple numpy arrays of same size, I want to create an array of equal size, which contains the extreme values of the arrays.

I have a working solution, but want to do this in a more pythonic way without the for loops if possible.

MWE

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[-3, 1], [5, -2]])
c = np.array([[2, -1], [1, -5]])

m, n = a.shape

out = np.zeros((m, n))
for ii in range(m):
    for jj in range(n):
        tmp = [a[ii, jj], b[ii, jj], c[ii, jj]]
        out[ii, jj] = tmp[np.argmax(np.abs(tmp))]

print(out)
# [[-3, 2], [5, -5]]
```

I have been thinking about a combination of `numpy.maximum.reduce` and `numpy.minimum.reduce`, but were not able to reproduce the above result.

Comment: its unclear what you are doing. could you elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```py
w = np.dstack([a,b,c])
y = np.abs(w)
x = np.argmax(y, axis=-1)

z = np.take_along_axis(w, np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), axis=-1)
np.reshape(z, (2,2))

array([[-3, 2],
       [5, -5]])
```

Comment: You were faster ;) Last step could be `np.take_along_axis(y, np.expand_dims(x, axis=-1), axis=-1)[..., 0]`

Answer (score 1):

In terms of readability and clearance of intention I would propose the following solution:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[-3, 1], [5, -2]])
c = np.array([[2, -1], [1, -5]])

data = np.stack([a, b, c], axis=0)
data_max = np.max(data, axis=0)
data_min = np.min(data, axis=0)

out = np.where(np.abs(data_max) > np.abs(data_min), data_max, data_min)
print(out)
```

Which prints:

```
[[-3  2]
 [ 5 -5]]
```

The main idea here is to reduce over the main axis with `min` and `max`, which I think communicates the intention of finding the extreme values more clearly.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

see code snippet with comment as explanation:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[-3, 1], [5, -2]])
c = np.array([[2, -1], [1, -5]])

# stack all arrays
d = np.stack([a, b, c])
# take argmax from absolute values
idx = np.argmax(np.abs(d), axis=0)
# take along axis
out = np.take_along_axis(d, np.expand_dims(idx, axis=0), axis=0)
# remove added dimension:
out = out.squeeze()

# or all in once:
out = np.take_along_axis(
    np.stack([a, b, c]),
    np.expand_dims(
        np.argmax(
            np.abs(
                np.stack([a, b, c])
            ),
            axis=0
        ),
        axis=0
    ),
    axis=0
).squeeze()
```